# Is it possible to intersect interests with Facebook Ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Today I heard of a company that is offering the possibility to target Facebook ads by intersecting interests.

Does anyone know if by using Facebook Ads API it would be possible to do this? Currently Facebook offers the possibility to select interests using this `or` that but I can't find a way to do this `and` that.

If anyone knows if this is possible and can point me out to any documentation and share experiences I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at flexible spec in the [targeting guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/v2.2#flexible).

For example, to target:

> people who live in the U.S,
>   aged between 20-24, who are not (single or married) and have not
>   recently moved and (are travelers or like soccer or movies) and are
>   (newlyweds or like music).

Specify targeting as:

```
targeting=
{'geo_locations':{ 
  'countries': ['US'], 
}, 
'age_min':20, 
'age_max':24, 
'flexible_spec': [ 
  { 
    'behaviors':[{'id':6002714895372,'name':'All travelers'},], 
    'interests':[ 
      {'id':6003107902433,'name':'Association football (Soccer)'}, 
      {'id':6003139266461, 'name': 'Movies'},],         
  }, 
  {
    'life_events':[{'id': 6002714398172, 'name': 'Newlywed (1 year)'}],
    'interests':[{'id':6003020834693,'name':'Music'},], 
  },   
  ], 
  'exclusions': { 
    'relationship_statuses':[1,3], 
    'life_events':[{'id':6003054185372,'name':'Recently moved'},], 
  }, 
}
```